# Scroll view of center aligned linear layout is wrapping top content in small resolution devices and landscape mode

Tags: android-layout, android

Scroll view of center aligned linear layout is wrapping top content in small resolution devices as well as landscape mode too.

but when i removed the center_vertical in linear lay out it is working fine, but i want that linear layout to be in center_vertical only.

Below is my code:!

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bodyscrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/app_update_alert_bg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/app_update_alert_bg_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo1" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/app_update_alert_bg_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo2" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/margin5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/switching_image_border"
                android:src="@drawable/switching_image_sb" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/margin5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/switching_image_border"
                android:src="@drawable/switching_image_ucc" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chckbox_dontshow_again"
                style="@style/margin5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo_dontshow" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_updatealert_confirmation"
                style="@style/buttonStyle.signInButton"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Because you used `android:fillViewport="true"` your ScrollView will strech to fill your screen height, thus making your `android:layout_gravity="center"` to do nothing. If you really need to center your layout use `android:gravity="center"`. 
Same goes for the child of the ScrollView, use `android:layout_gravity="center"`.
Another tip is to use padding in your ScrollView, instead of margin in the ScrollView child.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but i tried all those things before posted this question itself. 

I need some other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bodyscrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/app_update_alert_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/app_update_alert_bg_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo1" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/app_update_alert_bg_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/switching_image_border"
                android:src="@drawable/switching_image_sb"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/switching_image_border"
                android:src="@drawable/switching_image_ucc"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chckbox_dontshow_again"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                android:text="@string/updateinfo_dontshow"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_updatealert_confirmation"
                style="@style/buttonStyle.signInButton"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your Haresh, your code is perfectly working but here in my requirement i need parent should be scroll view only not Linear layout or relative layout also fine. Please tell me if you have any solution.